# How to split string to characters and then enclose every character with a tag

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar(50) field in SQL like this `34A450-45`, there is a need to separate them to characters and enclose every character in a span tag, so the expected result would be like this:

```
<span>3</span>
<span>A</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>0</span>
<span>-</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
```

I know that I might need a while loop, maybe a temp table and replace function but I have no idea how can I split a string to characters and then enclose every character in a certain tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this efficiently using a `cross join` and a tally/numbers table. This query usess a tally-table on the fly but a permanent solution would have a static table with 1-n values.

```
select Concat('<span>',Substring(s,n,1),'</span>')
from 
(values('34A450-45'))v(s)
cross apply (
    select n from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))n(n)
    where n.n<=Len(s)
)n
```

Comment: Note that the OP states that the column is a `varchar(50)`, so this will only work for the values that are 10 characters or less in length; any other characters will be truncated.

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was obvious this was just for an example of how to implement - I have added a comment for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a Tally; they are *significantly* faster than a rCTE:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (50) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2)
SELECT SUBSTRING(YT.YourColumn,T.I,1)
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON LEN(YT.YourColumn) >= T.I
ORDER BY YT.YourColumn,
         T.I;
```

If you need to have the value in XML, you can do something like this:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (50) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2)
SELECT SUBSTRING(YT.YourColumn,T.I,1) AS Span,''
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON LEN(YT.YourColumn) >= T.I
ORDER BY YT.YourColumn,
         T.I
FOR XML PATH('');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cedfda0c053ac497817450a0067c761c)

Answer (score -1):

One method for solving this is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), '34A450-45') as str, convert(varchar(max), '')  as c, 0 as lev
      union all
      select stuff(str, 1, 1, ''), left(str, 1) as c, lev + 1
      from cte
      where str <> ''
     )
select concat('<span>', c, '</span>')
from cte
where lev > 0
order by lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7be371e5b382bbd372f1334a3d9de41) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Why `CONVERT` the value to a `MAX` length? That is not going to be good for performance. And of course, the iteration is another matter.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I sincerely doubt that makes any difference on a query that returns 10 rows.

Comment: What, the recursion of the `MAX`? (I will note that the downvote is *not* mine if that's what got you to respond).

Comment: And no, for 10 rows there isn't an appreciable difference, but for larger sets, it does make a large difference. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8dbf49211c2516828bf6f603d8f5985)